# NHibernate casts to decimal when doing AVG

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I use nhibernate 3 with fluent mapping and MySQL5Dialect. I do grouping and trying to get average value:

```
var group = new TotalStatistic();
        SelectList(s => s
            .SelectGroup(t => t.RegistryName).WithAlias(() => group.Name)
            .SelectAvg(t => t.Value).WithAlias(() => group.Average))
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<TotalStatistic>());
```

But it generates sql query that contains cast to decimal and I get only zeroes in results instead of something like "0.0035" I suppose to get.

```
SELECT ... avg(cast(this_.Value as DECIMAL)) as y1_ ...
```

Comment: what datatype does the Value column have?

Comment: I believe I tried float, decimal and double with the same result

Comment: I'm willing to bet this is the same issue as [NH-2429] which was fixed in 3.3.0. I've added a bounty in case there is another cause or a workaround